# ansible role can't start apache via handler

Tags: ansible, ansible-handlers

I have this simple role for apache (in CentOS7):

*roles/apache/tasks/main.yml*

```
---
- name: Add epel-release repo
  yum:
    name: epel-release
    state: present

- name: Install Apache2
  yum:
    name: httpd
    state: present

- name: Insert Index Page
  copy:
    src: index.html
    dest: /var/www/html/index.html
```

*roles/apache/handlers/main.yml*

```
---
- name: Start Apache
  service: name=httpd state=started

- name: verify that the web service is running
  command: systemctl status httpd
  register: status_result

- name: debug
  debug: var=status_result
```

with-roles.yml - playbook same level as 'roles' directory

```
---
- name: Install apache2 in CentOS 7
  hosts: 1.23.4.56
  become: true
  roles:
    - apache
```

I then run the playbook as follows:

```
$ ansible-playbook -u root --private-key ~/.ssh/this_key.ppk with-roles.yml -i "1.23.4.56" -vvvv
```

Here's the tail-end part of the verbose output on screen:

```
    ...
    ...
    "mode": "0644", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "path": "/var/www/html/index.html", 
    "size": 11, 
    "state": "file", 
    "uid": 0
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
1.23.4.56              : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

but when I logged-in to 1.23.4.56, machine has the httpd installed but is stopped (which means that the handler didn't run). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A handler is only executed when it's notified.

See [Handlers: Running Operations On Change](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be in https://serverfault.com/questions/617548/always-trigger-handler-execution-in-ansible as per hints from René Pijl.

Specifically, I had to add this to the bottom of *roles/apache/tasks/main.yml*

```
...
...
- name: Apache Starter
  command: /bin/true
  notify: Start Apache
```

Comment: Instead of always notifying a handler, you might as well put the service state=started task in your tasks/main.yml playbook.